# How can I select a date from a table and pass it in as a parameter in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have one single date in one table.  I am trying to select this date and pass it into a function that pulls data from another system, based on this date parameter.  I think it should be something like this.

```
Declare @dateCurrent as DateTime
Set @dateCurrent = MyDate

SELECT @dateCurrent = DATEADD(Day,-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@dateCurrent,112)+'01')
Select top 1 ASOFDATE
FROM            dbo.fn_ExtractRawData('all', 'all', @dateCurrent)
```

I set 'MyDate' as a Variable.  I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.  Or, should I simply select the date from the table, like this.

```
Select AsOfDate
FROM DATE_RAW_DATA
```

No matter what I try, I'm getting an error that SSIS can't execute the query because the date parameter isn't coming in.  How can I get this setup correctly?  Thanks.

Comment: "Set @dateCurrent = MyDate"? That is not valid t-sql. What is MyDate? There is no from in that query.

Comment: So, 'MyDate' is the variable that I setup.  It's pulled from the table that has the date that I want.

Answer (score 1):

First, create an Execute SQL Task that gets the date value from your table and saves it into your variable.

Next, create another Execute SQL Task that is connected after the first task, and then use your variable in the query. Assuming you have the date saved in a variable named MyDate, your query for the second SQL Task would look like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ASOFDATE
FROM dbo.fn_ExtractRawData('all', 'all', DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),?,112)+'01'))
```

The question mark in the query means you're going to be using an input parameter for that value. So once you have the SQLStatement field value set, click on the "Parameter Mapping" option in the left pane of the Execute SQL Task Editor. For "Variable Name", select your variable from the drop down list, and for "Parameter Name" put 0 (which corresponds to the first question mark in the query). Make sure the variable data type and size are set correctly.